# How can i retrieve a qtableview from stored procedure in qt?

Tags: qt

I created a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TableView
AS
SELECT * 
FROM table
GO
```

When i call this sp on frontend what code i need to write to retrieve a qtableview?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I think a good option would be to store your model on the SQL Database and then retrieve the informations as needed. A good way to do so would be to use a Database table (or a Database view) as the model for the Qtableview. You can refer to this [QSqlRelationalTableModel Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlrelationaltablemodel.html) from QT documentation.